# Can an object be infinitely small?

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, quantum-gravity

I read somewhere that the earth has to be smaller than 1 cm to become a black hole, according to Schwarzschild. Since big bang came from a singularity, I am wondering, is there any minimum volume for anything?

Comment: I can't say there is a minimum volume per se, but there is a radius for a spherical object, smaller than which we cannot *measure* a volume

Comment: Ideal gases occupy 0 volume at absolute 0.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28720/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62003/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @user80551, ideal gases do not exist in day-to-day situations. The 0 volume is just an *approximation*

Comment: Adding to Jim's comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length).

Comment: @udiboy Ideal gas does not exist in holiday situations nor are they approximations! The ideal gas is a thought construct, not existing at all in real world. Light monatomic gas at very low pressuse approximates a ideal gas, not the other way!

Comment: [Planck length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Infinity is a mathematical term, very useful, but the history of physics has shown us that when we make mathematical extrapolations that lead to infinities of one sort or another, a different mathematical model will eliminate those infinities ( call me quantum mechanics).

In thermodynamics the black body radiation leads to the ultraviolet catastrophe, and quantum mechanics saves the day.

In classical electromagnetism, a point like electron would tend to an infinite potential at (0,0,0) as it goes with 1/r. Quantum electrodynamics saves the day.

That is because quantum mechanics has inherent probabilistic indeterminacies when sizes  become of order of *h*(the planck constant).

Even though elementary particles are postulated as point particles, they are not classical particles, the wave/particle duality saves the day, so the minimum volume would be of dimensions compatible with *h* in the variables examined and the measurement methods used.

Once gravity is quantized, the set will be complete, taking care of minimum black hole volumes too, in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can. An object can become infinitely small if it is compressed below its Schwarzschild radius. Gravitational singularities, which make a black hole, are objects with infinite density and 0 size.