# Singularity in a black hole

Tags: black-holes, mass, density, singularities

This might be a naive question, but how can an object such as a black hole singularity have infinite density but finite mass? (For example, we can approximate the mass of a black hole based on Kepler's Laws and use info from surrounding movements of stars to determine the central mass, but the black hole, excluding the event horizon, has infinite density.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25802/2451 More questions on density of black holes: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+[density]+[black-holes]

Comment: To speak about (mass) density, you need a mass $M$ and, admitting a spherical symmetry, a radius $R$. The only quantity you may use is the radius of the horizon, or [Schwartzschild radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius) $R_s$. For a Schwartzschild black hole, you have $R_s = \frac{2GM}{c^2}$. So you can calculate a "density". You will find, that, more the  black hole is big, more its "density" is low

Comment: Please see my answer in http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72927/ . You can apply it to the "infinite density" as well as to an infinitessimal volume.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to think about it is the following limit:
$$\rho = \lim_{V\to0}\frac{M}{V}$$

As $V\to0$, $\rho\to\infty$ while $M$ remains constant.