# Planck length, planck time, and planck rotation?

Tags: spacetime, physical-constants, discrete

given that there is a fastest speed at which anything can travel in our universe,299,792,458 meters per second, that seems to imply there may be a smallest distance in our universe, so first of all, is there any other evidence for or against a planck length being almost like a pixel through which energy can travel? am i wrong in thinking this?

and if so, i wonder, how many different directions could energy be transmitted out from a given 'planck-pixel' or unit of spacetime? is there some way that we could possibly test such an idea? have people already tried and to what degree?

so then that also makes me super curious, when it comes to an individual particle rotating, is there a smallest amount of rotation that can occur? or can the amount of rotation be infinitely divided? in other words, will we some day say that 0.00000009 (or whatever) degrees is the smallest amount of rotation any individual particle can move?

and conversely, is there a limit to how fast a particle can rotate? So basically, how many degrees of rotation can a particle spin over 1 planck length of time?

and how does rotation as *i* might tend to think of it, differ from rotation from the perspective of a particle, or 'spin', rather?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the Planck scale imply that spacetime is discrete?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9720/)

Comment: The speed of light is not about 299,792,458 m/s, it is exactly that, as the meter is derived from $c$ and the _second_.

Comment: See also [Is there a minimum possible rotation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296086), [Is the Planck length the smallest length that exists in the universe or is it the smallest length that can be observed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185939), and [Is time continuous or discrete?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35674)

Comment: The Plank length is much smaller than you may think. What amount of energy would we need in a particle accelerators to resolve the Plank length? There is a hundred billion stars like our Sun in our galaxy. There are 2000 galaxies in the Virgo Cluster. We'd need to burn them all up in some nuclear furnace, convert all that mass to energy and put it all into a single proton. Then it could drill down to the Plank length. It would be as heavy though as hundreds of trillions of stars. So this is not a matter of when, this is impossible, period. We'll never be anywhere near the Plank length or time.