# What things are smaller than the Planck length?

Tags: spacetime, physical-constants

I recently read [Is the Planck length the smallest length that exists in the universe or is it the smallest length that can be observed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185939/)

The general agreement is that the idea that the Planck length is the smallest length that exists is fallacious reasoning. So what is smaller than the Planck length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as we know, nothing. But the point of the Planck length is that anything smaller is not meaningful physically. Even string theory predicts entities larger than the Planck length: $10^{−33}$ m, compared to Planck's length which is in the order of $10^{−35}$m

The answer in your link says that we can't certainly say there's nothing smaller. That doesn't imply that there necessarily is something smaller than the Planck length.

Comment: Why do you think that anything smaller than plank length is physically not meaningful? Clearly we cannot extend this idea to plank mass which is in the order of $ \mu g$. What makes plank length then so special that anything smaller than that is physically devoid of meaning?