# How would a particle behave when its wavelength is lesser than a planck length

Tags: quantum-mechanics, temperature

If we increase the temprature of a body so much that its wavelength becomes lesser than the plank length, the quantum nature could breakdown as the wavelength of the particle is lesser than the so clained least possible length.

So my question is ...

How the particle will behave when it will go through such a transition?

does it mean that the existence of such a particle beyond this temperature collapses?

or it enters into a whole new state of matter where the particles behave entirely different like BEC?

Comment: No one expects physics to become classical at very small length scales. Perhaps temperatures above the Planck temperature are not possible. There is no agreement about what happens at or beyond the Planck scale.

Comment: The Planck length is *not* the "least possible length", cf. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185939/50583