# How can Planck-length elements exists in spacetime?

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, quantum-gravity, discrete

My question is simple, how can the theory of finite-sized elements (Planck-sized elements) in spacetime be correct, when you find the number $\pi$ in the Schwartzchild representation of the black hole, which implies that the black hole space-time curvature is composed of infinitely many space-time elements, as $\pi$ is a number which has infinitely many "decimals"? Clearly, the perfect ring of circumference $c$ is composed of infinitely many $\text{d}c$, and therefore the Planck limit should not exist at the space-time level, since a black hole cannot pertain to it as a subdivision of its spacetime geometry?

Comment: see also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185939/50583 for more discussion of the myth that the Planck length is about length being discrete in integral multiples of it.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151380/discussion-on-question-by-luthier415hz-how-can-planck-length-elements-exists-in); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.