# Is there a minimum distance?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spacetime, discrete, distance

I would imagine there is no limit to how small space can get. Is this correct? I am aware of planck's constant, but cannot objects be closer than Planck's constant is short?

Perhaps this question is simpler than I am making it to be. Regardless, an answer is appreciated.

Comment: Planck's constant is not a distance, but look at Planck length: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length

Comment: Possible duplicate of the second part of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28720/ ; see links therein.

Comment: I think you might want to look up Planck length.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9720/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28720/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62003/2451 and links therein.

Comment: If there was a minimum distance, it would take forever to measure, thanks to my old nemesis Heisenberg.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0203101

Comment: @g3n1uss wrote: *"Lubos Motl [answered](http://motls.blogspot.com/2009/09/myths-about-minimal-length.html) this question a long time ago."*

Comment: Oh-oh... @ACuriousMind got a golden tag badge... bad time is coming.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about the Planck lebgth, not the planck-constant.

But this is no minimum distance either. Its just the minimum space in which action can be defined. Its the distance, which is traveled trough by light in one planck second.

But that does not mean it is the smallest distance to exist.